unable to ping after stopping and restarting eth0
I did sudo ip link set eth0 down and then sudo ip link set eth0 up and where ping google.com worked before, doing it after yields this error:
ping: connect: Network is unreachable

Here's what ip link said about eth0 before:
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:5d:be:85:38 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

Here's what it says after:
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:15:5d:be:85:38 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

They look the exact same to me.
Is there something else I need to be doing for this to work?

How is network managed? Netplan or network-manager? Probably you need to restart whatever management service you use as well.

The output of ip link is less interesting in this case than the output of ip addr.
